# Auto mapping with non default entity manager in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Using the doctrine-bundle, I'm creating a bundle that requires a different database connection than the default one.

The bundle creates a new entity_manager, that uses the new connection through configuration:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    entity_managers:
       default:....
       my_custom_em:
          connection: my_custom_connection
          mappings:
            MyBundle: ~
```

When trying to access the repository with `$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('MyBundle:AnEntity');` I have the error:

```
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'MyBundle'.
```

But when using the name of the custom entity manager it works : `$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('MyBundle:AnEntity', 'my_custom_em');`

There is no way for doctrine to detect that `MyBundle` should be mapped to this entity manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `auto_mapping` can only be used when one connection is configured, so there is no simple one-line configuration which solve the problem.

Anyway there is a simple solution.

### Use the RegistryManager

Anyway, when you call `$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')` you get an instance of `ManagerRegistry` ([see the docs](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ManagerRegistry.php)), which have a method called `getManagerForClass`. With this method you can write code that don't rely on the connection configuration.

Your example will become:

```
$class = 'MyBundle:AnEntity';
$manager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManagerForClass($class);
$manager->getRepository($className)
```

### Define the ObjectManager as a service

If the special handling is required only for one bundle, you can take an even better solution from the previous approach.

You can define a service which will call the `RegistryManager` for you in a transparent way.

In `service.xml` you could write:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="my.entity.an_entity.class">Acme\MyBundle\Entity\AnEntity</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="my.manager"
             class="Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager"
             factory-service="doctrine" factory-method="getManagerForClass">
         <argument>%my.entity.an_entity.class%</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="my.an_entity_repository"
             class="Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository"
             factory-service="my.manager" factory-method="getRepository">
         <argument>%my.entity.an_entity.class%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

Your example will become:

```
$class = 'MyBundle:AnEntity';

$repository = $this->getContainer()->get('my.manager')->getRepository($class);
// or
$repository = $this->getContainer()->get('my.an_entity_repository')
```

Comment: What if you don't know the bundle shortcut? So is there a way to have a dynamic method that gets the entity manager for any entity that is passed in. e.g. Somehow do a lookup for the entities bundle, check the config to see what manager is mapped for that bundle, and get the entity manager applies to that entity...

Comment: Well, you "always know" bundle aliases, since it's the application configuration which define them. Symfony automatically configure `VendorPackageBundle` aliases for you, but you are free to override or unset them. Anyway, remember that aliases, are just that; you are not forced to use them and you can always access the entity by fully-qualified class name.

Comment: We are building a CMS that has lots of different content types being edited by generic controllers, so in a lot of cases we do not know what the Alias is for a given entity. I've constructed a nifty function to get the alias for an entity by using the doctrine utilities (no entity manager necessary). And then another to find the entityManager based on that bundle. It's pretty simple code actually, and works great.

Comment: See this reference question/answer for example of how to use the Doctrine Utility to get the Entity Class, or extract the Alias: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33248792/3334390