# Symfony2 - How to Dynamically get a Doctrine entity's Entity Manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

We are building a CMS and website building platform with a lot of different vendors and clients sites, so there are a lot of different content type entities, which are edited by generic controllers and helper services that don't necessarily (easily) know what the entity manager is for a given entity.

*NOTE: We have several entityManagers to separate access to different databases, e.g. Global, Billing, Local, etc*

There are many cases where we need to detect what is the entity's EntityManager. For example, we have a MediaHelper that dynamically associates media from a database with matching fields on the entity (this doesn't work with associations because the Media has to connect with literally any entity and you can't have that kind of dynamic association and we don't want a hundred different associations).

The media is in a bundle managed by the 'Local' EntityManager. But the entity may be in a 'Global' EntityManager (you can't assume it's in the same entity manager). So we need to detect and persist the right entity manager for the right entity.

***So how do you recommend dynamically detecting the entityManager for an entity?***

### Original Custom Method

**NOTE: the accepted answer is a much better solution. This is just here for archival purposes.**

Here is a simple solution that works. But I don't know enough about Symfony and Doctrine to know if it's a bad idea? Does anyone else know? If not, I don't know why this wouldn't be in the core, as a Doctrine Utility.

I created an EntityHelper service that injects the Doctrine service into it:

```
gutensite_cms.entity_helper:
    class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\Service\EntityHelper
    arguments:
        - "@doctrine"
```

Then in the entity helper is one simple function to get the Entity Manager for an entity (the config.yml registers the bundles for entity managers already):

```
/**
 * Automagically find the entityManager for an entity. 
 * @param $entity
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getManagerForEntity($entity) {
    $className = \Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getRealClass(get_class($entity));
    foreach (array_keys($this->doctrine->getManagers()) as $name) {
        if(in_array($className, $this->doctrine->getManager($name)->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getAllClassNames())) return $em;
    }
}
```

*NOTE: [Doctrine Registry#getAliasNamespace](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Registry.php) already does something nearly identical to this foreach loop, I just modified the idea to return the entity manager instead of the namespace, e.g.*

```
public function getAliasNamespace($alias) {
    foreach (array_keys($this->getManagers()) as $name) {
        try {
            return $this->getManager($name)->getConfiguration()->getEntityNamespace($alias);
        } catch (ORMException $e) {
        }
    }
    throw ORMException::unknownEntityNamespace($alias);
}
```

*Update 10/21/15: Entity Detection Code updated per @Cerad's suggestion.*

Comment: The `AbstractManagerRegistry` that `ManagerRegistry` extends has a method `getManagerForClass`. Would that do the job for you?

Comment: You are exactly right. That works very well. Originally I was stuck not knowing what the class was, without knowing the entity manager. But then I discovered the doctrine utilities that find that. So this would work quite well. I'll update my answer to reflect this option too.

Answer (score 1):

Per the suggestion of @qooplmao, there is an easy method already in the Doctrine core.

```
// 1) get the real class for the entity with the Doctrine Utility.
$class = \Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getRealClass(get_class($entity))

// 2) get the manager for that class. 
$entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManagerForClass($class);
```

*Updated 10/22/15 After suggestions from Cerad and Qooplmao*

Comment: I guess your basic approach of checking each entity manager to see if it supports the given entity class is the way to go.  I think your implementation might be a bit convoluted.  $entityManager->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getAllClassNames() should give you the data you need without fooling around with bundles names and aliases.

Comment: Great suggestion. I've updated with the simplified working code using your suggestion. Do you see any significant performance issues with this method that would discourage use? Is this something that would be useful enough to others to put in the core (so that we don't need to maintain our own version in future version changes).

Comment: I don't think the try/catch block is needed.  If, within a given request/response cycle, you anticipate calling this many times then perhaps a simple cache might speed things up a bit but probably not enough to be noticed.  As far as core goes, I suppose you could open an issue.  But this question is the first time I have ever seen something like this.  Not entirely convinced it's even needed but I'd have to understand the complete use case before attempting to suggest alternatives.  Be aware that you can configure multiple entity managers to manage the same entity type.

Comment: Yes, it always makes me wonder when I ask a question no one else seems to be asking. It makes me worried I'm going about it the wrong way. But that said, we all do build different platforms with unique needs, so it's bound to happen sometimes. We definitely aren't using Symfony like most people do, e.g. to build a single site. We are building a CMS website building platform, with multiple vendors, that has to be much, much more dynamic.

Comment: I'm trying to use this method in my bundle, but for some reason it does not work. It simply returns the manager that's defined first in the configuration.
I posted a question about it, but I haven't got an answer yet:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867556/symfony-2-8-doctrine-getmanagerforclass-not-returning-the-right-entity-manag

I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the way the mapping metadata is stored. Dis you use annotations? XML?

Comment: We use annotations on the entity for specifying repository, doctrine field metadata, etc. But we use YML to define the mapping of the bundles to specific entity managers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not give the entity manager a alias that suits the context it is for? You talk about Global, Billing, Local, so for example:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'global_entity_manager' => 'My\Global\EntityManager',
        'billing_entity_manager' => 'My\Billing\EntityManager', 
        'local_entity_manager' => 'My\Local\EntityManager',
    ),
)
```

---

You could also map the entity manager to the namespace of the entity.
So let's say you have a folder for your Global entities that is `Global\Entity`, then you could alias the entity manager for those entities `Global\Entity\EntityManager`. The advantage of this solution is that you can map several namespaces to the same entity manager, so your `Billing` and `Global` entities can easily share the same entity manager:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'aliases' => array(
        'Global\Entity\EntityManager' => 'My\Global\EntityManager',
        'Billing\Entity\EntityManager' => 'My\Global\EntityManager', // <-same name
        'Local\Entity\EntityManager' => 'My\Local\EntityManager',
    ),
)
```

This only works if your entities in one namespace are manager by the same `EntityManager` instance. I can hardly believe this would not be the case in any project, but otherwise you should maybe reorganize a bit? :D

Comment: Just be clear, this is in a Symfony project (with certain standards beyond just doctrine). We have multiple different `EntityManager` in order to split up data that is `Billing` (we don't want this on the same network as regular client content), and `Global` (universal info about accounts, sites, templates, etc), and `Local` (client content that is on smaller clusters and isn't accessed outside the cluster). So the config registers different bundles for different entity managers (which is essentially already doing what you are suggesting?).