# Symfony 2.8 : Doctrine getManagerForClass() not returning the right Entity Manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

tl;dr How does the `getManagerForClass()` method find out which entity manager is the right one for a specific class?

I've made a generic controller that should be able to handle basic actions for different entities.
I also have connections to two different databases, so I'm using two entity managers.

In my controller, I'm trying to use Doctrine's getManagerForClass() method to find which manager to use for each class, as explained [on this blog](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-the-manager-registry-instead-of-the-entity-manager/) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248856/5845942).

But the method does not seem to differentiate my two entity managers and simply returns the first one in the configuration.

My controller action starts like this:

```
public function indexAction($namespace, $entityName)
{
    $classFullName = "AppBundle:$namespace\\$entityName";
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass($classFullName);
```

This is my Doctrine configuration:

```
dbal:
    default_connection: postgres
    connections:
        postgres:
            driver:   pdo_pgsql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8

        oracle:
            driver:   oci8
            host:     "%oracle_host%"
            port:     "%oracle_port%"
            dbname:   "%oracle_name%"
            user:     "%oracle_user%"
            password: "%oracle_password%"
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    entity_managers:
        postgres:
            connection: postgres
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                   type:      annotation
                   dir:       Entity\Postgres
        oracle:
            connection: oracle
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                  type:       annotation
                  dir:        Entity\Oracle
```

And my folder structure is as follows:

```
AppBundle
    |___Controller
    |      |___EntityController.php
    |
    |___Entity
           |___Postgres
           |     |___SomePostgresBasedEntity.php
           |
           |___Oracle
                 |___SomeOracleBasedEntity.php
```

Now I don't know exactly how the method works, and how it it supposed to know about the mapping if not through the configuration.
But if I call it this way, for example:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass("AppBundle:Oracle\\SomeOracleBasedEntity");
```

...I get the entity manager for Postgres.

But if I simply switch the entity manager configuration, putting the one for oracle first, the previous call works, but the following doesn't:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass("AppBundle:Postgres\\SomePostgresBasedEntity");
```

## Update 1

`getManagerForClass()` cycles through every manager and for each one, checks if the class is "non-transient":

```
    foreach ($this->managers as $id) {
        $manager = $this->getService($id);

        if (!$manager->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($class)) {
            return $manager;
        }
    }
```

This goes all the way down to `AnnotationDriver->isTransient()`. Here the doc says the following:

> A class is non-transient if it is annotated with an annotation from the AnnotationDriver::entityAnnotationClasses.

`@Entity` seems to be one of those annotations that makes a class non-transient.
But then, how could any of my entities be transient at all? How could the driver distinguish an entity that belongs to a specific manager based solely on its annotations?
I must have missed something in the higher level classes.

## Update 2

The method works when using `yml` mappings.

I kind of expected this behaviour. The difference comes from the implementations of the isTransient() method in the different drivers. The FileDriver implementation of isTransient returns `true` if the metadata file exists in the `dir:` directory of the mapping configuration.

I would have expected the AnnotationDriver to search for annotations only in the entities contained in the specified `dir:` directory, but it seems to ignore that parameter.
Or should I use another one?

Comment: Kind of hoping someone knew the answer.  Looks like you will have to roll up your sleeves and start looking at the source code.  Be sure to report back when you figure it out.

Comment: You should try to set the path and alias options. If it still doesn't work maybe you should consider create a PostGreBundle and an OracleBundle to map your manager on them

Comment: @OlivierC I looked up the path and alias parameters. The former is not documented in Symfony, and I don't see haw the latter could help.
Could you provide examples?
I also tried the "prefix" parameter to no avail.
I'm looking for an option to make Doctrine search for annotations in the one and only specified directory, but I can't find one.

Comment: @OlivierC it was the `prefix` parameter after all.
@Cerad, it is done :)

Comment: @VictorToulouse yeah sorry, that was what i meant. Was on a hurry and didn't got time to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At long last, I solved it.
The solution was using the `prefix` parameter.

```
entity_managers:
    postgres:
        connection: postgres
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
                type: annotation
                dir: Entity\Postgres
                prefix: AppBundle\Entity\Postgres
                alias: Postgres
    oracle:
        connection: oracle
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
                type: annotation
                dir: Entity\Oracle
                prefix: AppBundle\Entity\Oracle
                alias: Oracle
```

## Explanation

The `prefix` parameter gets passed to the corresponding Entity Manager service, and is added to the `entityNamespaces` property, which otherwise defaults to `AppBundle/Entity`.
The Annotation Driver will then check for annotations *in that specific namespace*, whereas the File Driver checks for existing mapping files in the directory specified through the `dir` parameter.
(The `alias` parameter is not mandatory.)

At least, that's how I understand it.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this problem and this looked like a solution, but it turns out I had the prefix parameter set already, and it's set correctly.  Still digging.

Comment: Note:  I found that I had to put my default entity manager config last to get this to work.