# not returning correct EntityManager Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, security, doctrine, entitymanager

I am implementing symfony security. My User entity is in another database. I have multiples enties managers. So far I can't get the entitymanager to read  User table, which in my case is not the default entitymanager.

This is my security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            id: 'App\Security\Encoder\MyCustomPasswordEncoder'
            #app_encoder:
            #para oracle
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Trimu\User
                property: email
                manager_name: trimu
                #https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/entity_provider.html
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                #target: app_logout
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 2592000 # 30 days in seconds

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

this is my doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            trimu:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'oci8'
                server_version: ~
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_SECURITY_URL)%'
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        #auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            trimu:
                connection: trimu
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Trimu'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Trimu'
                        alias: App
```

As you see my entity App\Entity\Trimu\User is in other directory and prefix. I have read: [Symfony 2.8 : Doctrine getManagerForClass() not returning the right Entity Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867556/symfony-2-8-doctrine-getmanagerforclass-not-returning-the-right-entity-manag) and I have the same question: How does the getManagerForClass() method find out which entity manager is the right one for a specific class?

Thank you.

**SOLVED, Thanks friends**

I changed all prefix an all directory now it work fine.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            trimu:
                # configure these for your database server
                driver: 'oci8'
                server_version: ~
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_SECURITY_URL)%'
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        #auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Mysql'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Mysql'
                        alias: App
            trimu:
                connection: trimu
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Trimu'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Trimu'
                        alias: App
```

As Stev say:
Your first entity manager is covering all the entities because of :

```
dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
```

Comment: getManagerForClass simply checks each entity manager (in the order they are defined) and picks the first one that maps the desired entity.  Does not always work as desired.  If you can adjust the mappings per the answer below then great.  If you need both managers to map the user entity then you will need to manually adjust the entity manager injections.  Which is another big can of worms.

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problem. ALL directories must be changed (through the dir parameter), because they are the key to finding the correct entity manager. I hope this helps someone else. I could finally understand it by reading: https://php.developreference.com/article/15121219/Symfony+2.8+%3a+Doctrine+getManagerForClass()+not+returning+the+right+Entity+Manager

Comment: how can i neatly attach my correct doctrine.yaml i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Click on 'edit' just under the lower left corner of your question.

Comment: Instead of adding a **SOLVED** section to your question consider submitting an answer, then you can accept it and it can help others. Otherwise people skimming the search results will assume that _it hasn't_ been solved.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your first entity manager is covering all the entities because of :

> dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'

Change your folder structure so that each EntityManager has it's own folder where to find the mappings.
Example:

```
entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/App'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\App'
                    alias: App
        trimu:
            connection: trimu
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Trimu'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity\Trimu'
                    alias: Trimu
```